# Is it possible to partially autoformat the code?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a java project with 3 other people using eclipse. I tend to use the 'CTRL + SHIFT + F' (auto format) shortcut a lot. Since everybody seems to have their own format settings, it is very annoying to check for changes in git commits. If someone autoformats git deletes giant blocks of code and replaces them with the new formatted code. This makes spotting the important changes somewhat difficult.

In the future we will all use the same 'Java > Code Style > Formatter' but I guess that this problem can occur quite frequently. So my question is: is it possible to format only a block of code without formatting the whole class? Say we have a class with 100 lines, I add a new method and want my formatter only be applied to my method...

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Related: [eclipse reformat only edited lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18643378/5515060), as that question is 7 years old I don't know if newer eclipse version have support for this issue

Comment: Not sure about Eclipse, but in IntelliJ if you select a range of text and then auto-format it will only format the selected text.

Comment: Select the block you want to format then press CTRL + SHIFT + F. It will format only the selected code. If you select nothing, the entire file gets formatted.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Just tested it, works fine :)

Comment: As a side note to overcome this in the future. You could take a look at: https://github.com/google/google-java-format that will automatically format your code. You could also include it using maven in your project such that everyone will have to use it.

Comment: Code Style > Formatter values are also settable on the project itself from the Properties dialog.

Comment: @nitind That sound like a good feature. i ll check it out!

Comment: @Bram sounds interesting. Ill check it out!

Comment: @Bram Better use the built-in _Save Actions_ for that.